# How to get all balances for some account using Web3.js and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I'm new in the blockchain technology, moreover in some dev tasks related to the blockchain. Nevertheless, suddnely I was asked to implement such a demo back-end Node.js app that:

**Task: Get information about all tokens for some wallet address.**

For example:

Input:
The wallet address is: `0xB245ac044E3c2e9781C9c848249E2e6b186b080F`

Output:

```
ERC-20 tokens: USDT $100, USDC $200, SHIB $300;
Etherum native token: ETH $500.
```

I'm not asking about ready-to-use code snippet (but why not?), rather it would be better to know which steps should be proceeded in general using Node.js and Web3.js specifics.

**Where I've tried to find the answer:**

- *Stackoverflow:* [How to get all tokens by wallet address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085393/how-to-get-all-tokens-by-wallet-address)
- *Stackoverflow:* [web3.js how to search all the contracts ever created by and address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938672/web3-js-how-to-search-all-the-contracts-ever-created-by-and-address)
- *Stackexchange:* [How to get all contracts deployed by the address, given the address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62695/how-to-get-all-contracts-deployed-by-the-address-given-the-address)
- *Github:* [ERC-20-Token-Balance](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/ERC20-Token-Balance) (cool and very simple hello-world project)
- *Medium:* [Try out Ethereum using only nodejs and npm!](https://medium.com/@codetractio/try-out-ethereum-using-only-nodejs-and-npm-eabaaaf97c80)

Each of these helps to understand some moments, but the whole solution is still not obvious for me.

It is very possible that I am missing something for input, also possible that my output is incorrect in some moments. But I hope the general idea of the question is clear more or less.

Answer (score 1):

I'll split your question into several steps, as there is no simple way to fetch the data from the blockchain in the format you want, so you have to "walk a thorny path".

###### 1. Get the list of Token Addresses owned by an Externally-Owned-Account

###### 1.1 Query for `Transfer` events

A token, or better to say - a contract, which implements the `ERC20` interface, emits an `event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)` Event every time the token transfer occurs. You can query the blockchain for the [past events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getPastLogs#getpastlogs), where the `to` is your target account. The event emitters are the contracts, possibly the `ERC20` tokens, but also those could be the `ERC721` tokens, as they have the same event signature in the interface.

> Also notice, an event emitter could be any contract, even not related to tokens, as any contract can emit any event.

> Some blockchain nodes could limit the block ranges per request to get the events from, so you have to implement the pagination, as you want to get events from block `0` to `latest`

###### 1.2 Find out the `ERC20` Tokens

You have here several options

a. You can create the list of known tokens from various 3rd party sources (CoinmarketCap, 1inch, Shushiswap, Uniswap) and then filter those `Transfer` emitters narrowed to those from the known list.

b. Another option, is to fetch `ERC20` interface Information directly from the blockchain.  Call each `Transfer` emitter by getting the `decimals`, `name`, `symbol`, `balanceOf`. If you don't get the exception for the calls, then the contract is highly likely the `ERC20` token.

c. Or you can get the contracts ABI (if the contract is validated) from Etherscan, and check if everything from `ERC20` interface exists in the ABI.

I have implemented all these steps in the [`0xweb`](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) cli tool, which uses the [`dequanto`](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto) library. You can check the implementation in [CTokens.ts#L88](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb/blob/55b759ee4930a5255b88202718f78e6c44b11188/src/commands/list/CTokens.ts#L88)

---

After these steps, you'll get the list of all tokens owned by the account, and their amounts (`balanceOf`).

###### 2. Get the token prices

Another challenging task, in case you don't use any 3rd party service and stick to onchain data.

a. Query the oracle price feeds like [chain.link](https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd/eth-usd). But not all tokens are presented there.

b. Get the price directly from DEX, like uniswap, sushiswap, pancakeswap etc. But surprise - no easy way to get the price also here. You can find a stable pair (Some USD stable coin/Your Token), if the pair exists just grab the reserves and the ratio is the price. For less popular tokens there could be only the `ETH/YourToken` pair, and the price for `ETH` you can get these steps `a)` or `b)`.

I've written a more in-depth article: https://dev.kit.eco/ethereum-get-token-price-at-a-specific-block-onchain on how to get the price at any time in the past. And if you don't have the archive node, you just get the price for the `latest` block.

---

*If you want me to explain some parts in detail, don't hesitate to ask in the comments, I'll update the answer then.*